# General solution to differential problem with $dy/dx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am given $\frac{dy}{dx} + 6y=e^x$ and I am trying to find the general solution but I am struggling. Can someone solve it out? Thanks

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. It is best to include any ideas you may have, or to provide some context for the problem.

Comment: Looks like a linear first order differential equation to me

Answer (score 0):

If
$$
y'+6y=e^x
$$
then we can multiply both sides by the integrating factor $e^{6x}$
$$y'e^{6x}+6ye^{6x}=e^{7x}
$$
Now observe that
$$
(ye^{6x})'=y'e^{6x}+6ye^{6x}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: So I realized that (ye^(6x))’ = e^7x so took the integral of both sides and got ye^(6x)=e^(7x)/7 so I put the y on one side and got the answer y=(1/7)e^x is this correct? Again, I’m struggling with the solution.

Comment: Close, there’s an integration constant you need to take into account

Comment: I added the constant at the end so that y(x) = (1/7)e^x + C. Is this right? If not please correct me.